# USB Device Connected

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, usb

I'm trying to make a function that detects if a usb device is connected given the devices pid and vid.  I'm hoping it would look something like this, I'm just not sure how to do this in C#.

```
public bool IsUsbDeviceConnected(string pid, string vid)
{
  //Code here
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. What results did you get? 3. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//using System.Management
public bool IsUsbDeviceConnected(string pid, string vid)
{   
  using (var searcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"))
  {
    using (var collection = searcher.Get())
    {
      foreach (var device in collection)
      {
        var usbDevice = Convert.ToString(device);

        if (usbDevice.Contains(pid) && usbDevice.Contains(vid))
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me out with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7314257/75500) related question?

Answer (score 3):

may be something like

```
//import the System.Management namespace at the top in your "using" statement. Then in a method, or on a button click:

ManagementObjectCollection collection;
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'"))
  collection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in collection)
{
  ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
  MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());
}
collection.Dispose();
```

Using WMI

Comment: I don't have a serial number, only the vendor id and product id which is nested somewhere in the usb.  Also that WMI call looks for Win32_DiskDrives, not all USB devices.