# What USB devices (friendly name) are currently connected to PC?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb, device

Can I get a list of what devices are currently connected to the computer?

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331043/75500) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685615/usb-device-connected) thread, but I can't seem to find the actual names (i.e. iPod Touch 4 etc.) is there a way to find the name of the device in human language, so I can display this list (of matching devices) to the user?

Any PI that gets this info?

**Update:** I notice that the computer's device management is able to show this info, meaning it does exist somewhere, I just don't know the right place to access it.

I did found this info in the registry, but there is some inconsistency between the "Mighty Drive" and the "iPod", I'm looking for a reliable reg. key to seek for this info.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Device Manager shows the first "Display Name" property associated with a particular device. You can get that information using [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with, I believe, the `SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME` property.