# c# Listening for physical scan button events on scanners

Tags: c#, usb, scanning

I tried to connect to a usb port on which a scanner is connected with different apis like libusbdotnet, icharpusb and this: http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/projects/usb-hid-driver-library/

To sum it up, i need to listen to data on a usb port, where a scanner is connected, and catch an event when a physical button for scanning is pressed. Is it possible to do something like that in csharp without digging in unmanaged code?

Comment: is it really possible to do it in csharp?

Comment: i did give it a shot, told you i tried with libusbdotnet, icharpusb and above api from florian

Comment: This is very similar question to [How to get signals from a scanner connected over usb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940754/how-to-get-signals-from-a-scanner-connected-over-usb)